# .remove() function in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Suppose, I have a list of 5 items and I want the user to be able to delete his desired entry from the list. In this case, if I use jQuery, I can point to the particular delete button class and use 'this' to point its closest parent and then use '.remove()' to remove it from the DOM. Example:

```js
$('.delete').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
})
```

```css
ul li {
padding:0.5em;
list-style-type:none;
margin-bottom:0.5em;
}

ul li span a {
margin-left:100px
}

ul li span a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>Item 1<span class="delete"><a>Delete</a></span></li>
<li>Item 2<span class="delete"><a>Delete</a></span></li>
<li>Item 3<span class="delete"><a>Delete</a></span></li>
<li>Item 4<span class="delete"><a>Delete</a></span></li>
<li>Item 5<span class="delete"><a>Delete</a></span></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to whether I can have the same functionality in Angular 2?

Real Scenario code is:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'myLevels',
  template: `
      <template #clone>
        <div class="addedLevel">
        <p>Paragraph Two</p>
        <span #element><i class="fa fa-trash deleteLevel" (click)="removeLevel()"></i></span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <div #container></div>

      <button (click)="cloneTemplate()">Clone Template</button>
  `,
})

export class level implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  // What to clone
  @ViewChild('clone') template: any;

  // Where to insert the cloned content
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: any;

  cloneTemplate() {
    this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // $(document).on('click', '.deleteLevel', function() {
    //   $(this.closest('.addedLevel')).remove();
    // })
  }

  removeLevel() {
    debugger;
    console.log(this.element);
    this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.addedLevel').remove();
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Try *ngFor for repeatation of items and (delete) event binder and emitter. Refer Angular 2 documents.

Comment: Ok, the real scenario is that I have one HTML template, which I am cloning and appending to a parent div using selector. This is having a delete icon too in it. Now, I want to have the same functionality as above on this. Please note that I am not using *ngFor in this case. Cloning the template and appending on a button click.

Comment: Real scenario code?

Comment: Hi Amit, I have edited the question to show you the real code, you can check it there. I am sorry if the code looks a bit messy as it is still an app under development. As you can see, I have resorted to jQuery as of now, so looking for an Angular solution.

Comment: You should use `*ngFor` to render elements, and then modify the array you bind to `*ngFor` and let `*ngFor` do the adding/removing of DOM elements. Try to avoid direct DOM manipulation in Angular2 and especially try to avoid to do it using jQuery.

Comment: Is it possible to append one complete HTML template from an array? I am new to Angular2, so as per my understanding, *ngFor will render array elements as plain text and not HTML elements. However, I need to render HTML elements here.

Comment: What is issue with your angular code? Is it deleting only last element which has been cloned or it is not working at all ! In addition to this HTML templates in angular are plain HTML fragments with Angular bindings and directives in addition.

Comment: everything works fine, the only issue is that when I click on the delete icon, it looks into the DOM and finds the first 'addedLevel' class and deletes it rather than deleting the div where the click happened.

Comment: This will happen @SunitS as the search anchor is same (#element). So for this it will point to single node. If you have mechanism like #element1, #element2 then your code will work after passing this to delete function. But avoid all this and use *ngfor .

Comment: I know and I completely agree with you Amit regarding usage of *ngFor, that will make a lot of things easier for me. I just need someone to guide me how to append HTML template on a button click to a div using *ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, there's absolutely no need to even access the DOM yourself. Angular takes care of that for you. Just bind to an array in your component using `ngFor` and mutate that array using a method on your component.

See here for a quick example: https://plnkr.co/edit/bGlsxog3tx13aszBv84u?p=preview

Comment: The example is a good one, however, the issue remains the same, I am not concerned about generating 'li' elements from array using *ngFor. My issue is that after appending HTML elements and tags from the cloned templates, how do I delete the particular 'div' where the click happened.

Comment: You can pass `$event` as a parameter to the click function, which will send the raw event data. Then, I suppose, get the `srcElement` property of that. That gives you the element that fired the click event and you can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

html file

```
 <form #newForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="savenew(newForm)">
 <ul>
 <li *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="name{{index}}" class="form-control" 
     name="name{{index}}" ngModel #name{{index}}="ngModel" value=
   {{item.name}}>
    <input type="text" id="age{{index}}" class="form-control" 
   name="age{{index}}" ngModel #age{{index}}="ngModel" value={{item.age}}>
    <button type="Button" (click)="remove(index)" >Remove</button>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" (click)="addb()">Add</button>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS file

```
 items: any[] = [
 { name: '', age :'' }
 ];
 addb(){
  this.items.push({name:'',age:''});
 }
 remove(index: number): void {
  this.items.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

@sunit Hope this what u expected